# Objects are not valid as a React child (object with keys) React native

Tags: api, react-native

Trying to display Api data with Fetch, wanted to know how can i only bring only 'brand' in the return.Getting Error 'Objects are not valid as a React child: object with keys {all}. If you mean to render a collection of children use an array instead'.

```
 export default App = () => {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
  fetch('https://', {
        method: 'POST',
        timeout: 10000,
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },

        }) 
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
     // .then((responseData) => { console.log(responseData); })
       .then((responseData)=> setData(responseData))
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false)); [fetch, data];
    }, []);

    return (

<ScrollView>
         <View style= {styles.container}>
            <Text> {data.data}  </Text>
         </View>
         </ScrollView>
```

My Sample api return value

```
Object {
  "data": Object {
    "all": Array [
      Object {
        "brand": "A1",
      },
      Object {
        "brand": "B1",
      },
      Object {
        "brand": "C1",
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default App = () => {
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
fetch('https://', {
    method: 'POST',
    timeout: 10000,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },

    }) 
})
    .then((response) => response.json())
 // .then((responseData) => { console.log(responseData); })
   .then((responseData)=> setData(responseData.data))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
    .finally(() => setLoading(false)); [fetch, data];
}, []);

return (

    <ScrollView>
     <View style= {styles.container}>
        {data.map((value,index)=>(<Text key={index}>{value.brand}</Text>)}
     </View>
     </ScrollView>
   )
  }
```

1. You should use a map to access an array of objects.
2. You should add proper keys in response to avoid side effects.